# Error When Installing PHP5 on IIS6

Tags: php, iis-6, php5, fastcgi

I am trying to install PHP on my Windows Server 2003 machine that is using IIS6.
I followed [this guide](http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/php2003/) for installing it, including using the binaries of fastCGI. I think I did everything correctly, however, when I went to create my phpinfo(); page I get the following:
Server Error, unable to connect to fastcgi server.

I've tried looking in all the logs I can think of. Nothing in IIS log that is helpful, PHP never even logged an error or anything and nothing in my events log.

Help Please and Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's a pretty out of date blog entry and life has moved on substantially since then. So forget everything you read on that page :)

**1. Download PHP:**

Download the latest stable version of PHP for windows. In this case download the PHP 5.3.6 x86 Non Thread Safe zip file (note: the version number may change as the PHP team release new stable binaries):

> http://windows.php.net/download/
>   http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.3.6-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip

Extract the contents of the zip file to a folder called `C:\PHP` so that in this folder you have the following subfolder structure:

```
C:\PHP\dev , C:\PHP\ext , C:\PHP\extras, etc
```

Rename one of the `php-*.ini` files to `php.ini` and edit according to any requirements you may have.

**2. Install/Configure Microsoft's FastCGI Extension for IIS5.1/6.0:**

Install Microsoft's IIS6 FastCGI extension which can be downloaded from here:

> http://www.iis.net/download/fastcgi

Once installed, edit `C:\Windows\System32\InetSrv\fcgiext.ini` so that it contains only the following:

```
[Types]
php=PHP

[PHP]
ExePath=C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe
```

**3. Configure IIS PHP Scriptmap:**

Edit or add the `.php` scriptmap to your chosen website (or you can add globally) by right clicking on the site and choosing properties:

[image]

Choose the `Home Directory` tab and click `Configuration`:

[image]

Click `Add` (or if you still have the `.php` scriptmap listed, then remove it and re-add).

You need to populate the Executable and Extension fields with these values:

```
Executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\fcgiext.dll
Extension: .php
```

Click OK and save these changes.

**4. Configure PHP FastCGI Settings in PHP.INI:**

Open `C:\PHP\php.ini` in an editor and locate and configure these settings:

```
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
cgi.force_redirect = 0
date.timezone = Europe/London  ; (http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
```

It seems you need to set the timezone now for the `phpinfo();` page to render properly, but it's a good idea to set this anyway.

**5. Test PHP:**

Create a file called `test.php` with the following:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Browse to this page and if all is good you should see:

[image]

After that it's all up to you to fine tune your configuration such as deciding which extensions to use and so on.

**After Thoughts:**

Depending on how your system is set up you may need to adjust the permissions on the `C:\PHP` folder. If it's a pretty stock installation and your sites are running in application pools using the Network Service account and you're using the generated `IUSR_<MACHINE_NAME>` anonymous account then you shouldn't need to change anything.

Comment: I forgot to update this :P I ended up switching to fastCGI from iis.net and it solved the problem, you have a very good guide there though, thanks a lot.

e: uff, I don't have 15 rep yet on this site so I can't "up" your answer yet, will "up" it later once I get the rep.

Comment: @numone - I just gave you a bump to 20 for the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find errors in the php log in 
C:\WINDOWS\temp\php-errors.log

They only appear in the event log if you modify your php.ini file (in c:\windows if you've followed those instructions) and take out the semicolon on the line

> ;error_log=syslog

Comment: Actually looks like he's using a horribly out of date installation guid dating back to the ark.