# HTML page on IIS 6

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, iis-6, html

I always been about Linux webservers.

I need to make a simple page for intranet users. 
I was reading a guide how to setup a webpage in IIS.

But as far as I understand it doesn't capable of simply reading html files?

How can I use simple html pages, or php applications?
If IIS isn't capable for PHP, could someone provide a small third party application, which could be easy on system resources?

The server which I am dealing with is Windows Server 2003

Thanx for anything!

**Update:**

I've followed this [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972/en-us) as suggested below. 
THat guide described pretty the same what I was doing before:

1. I've navigated to IIS 6 administration,
2. Created a website by the help of wizard,
3. Set the home directory,
4. The home directory contains one simple file, index.html which simply should display hello.
5. I clicked "Browse" in ISS manager, to view the site. No results.

I know that the ISS works fine, there is Sharepoint services running on the same amchine..

What I am missing here?

**Update2:**

I am attaching a [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/usfq1nacv/) of all my sites on that machine.

**Update3:**

I solved this problem, it appears that IIS didn't like my host header value. It was set to wiki.local

One last question though, how can I setup, so that the page could be accessed by some kind of wording. Like wiki.local for example.

I believe these are the settings in DNS manager in windows server? Or can't it be done at all?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you don't understand how DNS works in relation to web sites.  I recommend reading up on DNS and name resolution.  The short answer is you will need to set up an A record in DNS for whatever you decide to call your site.  This would be in public DNS if it is an external site, or in internal/AD DNS if it is strictly internal.  This will allow clients to resolve your name to the appropriate IP, allowing them to browse the site.

Comment: I understand how the dns works. I just never done it in windows, so is was a bit tricky how the folders were appearing in dns manager :) Everything is soled now, thank you very much :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS can certainly serve HTML, it is a normal web server in that respect.  Microsoft provides [a KB article on how to set up your first IIS6 website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972/en-us).

It can also be used to serve PHP if it is installed appropriately.  On IIS7+ you can use the Web Platform Installer to easily install and configure PHP for IIS.  On IIS6 it is a bit different.  [This ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/251499/error-when-installing-php5-on-iis6/252149#252149) provides a pretty good way to do it quickly and effectively.

Comment: Without seeing the bindings for all sites its tough to know.  I suggest you edit your question to include a screenshot displaying the bindings for all of your existing sites.

Comment: Thanx, I've updated the question.

Comment: Which site is the one you've created?  Your Default Web Site is stopped at the moment.  Also, what appears in your brower's address bar after you hit "browse"?  You need to make sure your site is not bound to the same binding combination as your SP site.

Comment: I've created the IT one. It simply appears that the website can't be displayed..

Comment: Do you have wiki.local set up in DNS or the HOSTS file?  If so, open a browser and type "http://wiki.local:4568/".  You need to include the port because you are running it on a port other than 80.